# How to estimate the numbers of the integer points of $\frac{(m-1)(m-2)}{2}+k\leq N$,
$a\leq\frac{k}{m}\leq b$

Tags: number-theory, elementary-number-theory, nonlinear-optimization, integer-lattices

How to estimate the numbers of the integer lattices of
$$\frac{(m-1)(m-2)}{2}+k\leq N$$
$$a\leq\frac{k}{m}\leq b$$
Here , m,k are the variables , b,a  are selected, N can tend to the infinity, well, the result may be
$$(b-a)N+O(\sqrt{N})$$